# Trouble with loops and flow control in my Java Networking project

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a Number guessing game that has a Client that takes in guesses and outputs the result, and a Server that receives said guesses, compares them to a randomly generated number and tells the client if the guess was too high, low or correct. At the moment I just don't understand why the Server isn't replying to the Client. I think I am making a flow control mistake somewhere, but am stumped as to where my mistake lies.. any help is greatly appreciated!

Client:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("This is Number Guessing Game. \nChoose any number between 1 to 1000 : ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);



        try {  
            Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 8093);



            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                    client.getInputStream()));

            boolean haswon=false;
            int i=0;

            while(i<11){
                i++;
                int guess = s.nextInt();
                out.writeInt(guess);  
                out.flush();

                String result = in.readUTF();  
                System.out.println(result);
                haswon = in.readBoolean();
                if(haswon=true){
                    System.out.println("You Win! :D");
                    i=11;}else{continue;}


            }

            client.close();
            System.out.println("Game over. Thank you");
            System.exit(0);

        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        Socket client = null;
        boolean haswon;

        int guess = 0;
        int random = 0;
        int timer = 0;
        String end;
        String lwrong;
        String hwrong;
        String win;


                try {
                    socket = new ServerSocket(8093);
                    System.out.println("The server socket has started and ready to receive client connection.");
                    client = socket.accept();


                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                            client.getInputStream()));
                    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                            client.getOutputStream()));


                    while(timer<11){ 
                        guess = input.readInt(); 
                        random=(int)(Math.random()*100);
                        if (guess < random){ 
                            lwrong="Your guess was too low, try again.";
                            output.writeUTF(lwrong);
                            System.out.println("successh");
                            haswon=false;
                            output.writeBoolean(haswon);
                            timer++;                                                    
                        }else if(guess > random){
                            hwrong="Your guess was too high, try again";  
                            output.writeUTF(hwrong);
                            System.out.println("successl");
                            haswon=false;
                            output.writeBoolean(haswon);
                            timer++;    
                        }else if(guess==random){
                            win="Correct!";
                            output.writeUTF(win);
                            System.out.println("successw");
                            timer=8;
                            haswon=true;
                            output.writeBoolean(haswon);
                            output.flush();
                            timer++;
                            break;  
                        }
                        continue;


                        }
                        while(timer==7){
                            end="Out of Guesses, the correct answer was: ";
                            output.writeUTF(end);
                            output.flush();
                            break;                    
                        }








                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.err.println("Error Connecting "+ ioe);
                        return;
                    }




            client.close();
            socket.close();
                }

}
```

Comment: Are your `System.out.println`s on the server being executed? If they are, your problem may be that you're flushing the output stream only when the guess is correct.

Comment: Besides, the `while(timer==7)` part is not actually a loop, it may be rewritten as an `if`.

Comment: Please take some time to clean up the code, it does not only help to read it, but it will also allow you to better understand it. You can for example remove the `else { continue; }` at the end of a loop. I would not have a counter limit in the client, let the server decide. And the server should decide if it wants 11 or 8 as a limit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the random number outside the loop, otherwise it will change on each guess. You also must out.flush() in the server after you write the strings - you only do that for the win case. The `while(timer == 7)`can be removed completely, at this point in execution you can just write to the client unconditionally.